# What is the best wat to parse a JSON lines string

Tags: node.js

I am receiving exactly the next message from a request. I want to parse this message into an array of JSON. If you see there is "\n" at the end of each line, and also between each sub-message, there is a symbol "+".

```
t = '{ "messages": { "brand": "x", "reqQuery": "productIds=1", "cliIP": "117.0019.111.51", "cliPort": "xxx", "reqMethod": "GET", "fwdHost": "app-xx-v2-xxxnas.xxx.io", "bytes": "853", "reqHost": "xx-bff-v2-xxxxs.xxx.io", "UA": "xxx-android-3.38.1-210001759", "respCT": "application/json", "reqPath": "/prod_ids", "status": "200" }, "reqHdr": { "referer": "-" }, "respHdr": { "date": "2020-09-16T02:42:23+00:00" }, "netPerf": { "request_time": "0.000", "upstream_status": "-", "upstream_connect_time": "-", "cacheStatus": "HIT" }, "waf": { "riskGroups": "-" } }\n' + '{ "messages": { "brand": "x", "reqQuery": "productIds=2", "cliIP": "111.113.113.618", "cliPort": "46215", "reqMethod": "GET", "fwdHost": "app-bff-v2-xxxnas.xxx.io", "bytes": "3351", "reqHost": "app-bff-v2-x.xxx.io", "UA": "xxx-android-3.38.1-210001759", "respCT": "application/json", "reqPath": "/product_cells_by_ids", "status": "200" }, "reqHdr": { "referer": "-" }, "respHdr": { "date": "2020-09-16T02:42:23+00:00" }, "netPerf": { "request_time": "0.177", "upstream_status": "200", "upstream_connect_time": "0.000", "cacheStatus": "EXPIRED" }, "waf": { "riskGroups": "-" } }\n'
```

What is the better way to parse it using NODEJS? I tried

```
JSON.stringify(t).split("\\n"),
```

but the first element of the resulted array has the additional symbol '"' which spoils the JSON element. Could you help me please, to

Comment: Calling `JSON.stringify()` on an already stringified JSON is probably not what you want to do...

Comment: Why is `messages` an object instead of an array as the name suggests?

Comment: @leun4m thanks you by your attention. I agree with you, but this variable comes from a third party client.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach:

1. Replace all newlines with a comma
2. Remove the last comma (otherwise you won't get a valid JSON)
3. Put your modified string into brackets
4. Parse it using `JSON.parse()`

```js
let a = t.replaceAll("\n",",")
// Remove the last char if that is a ','
if (a[a.length - 1] === ",") {
  a = a.substring(0, a.length - 1)
}
JSON.parse(`[${a}]`)
```